# How to read this PDA?

Tags: computation-theory, pushdown-automaton

[image: PDA]

This is an old HW question where I had to find out how many times the q\loop state was visited for each given string:

bb: 5

abab: 0

abba: 8

babbab: 11

I understand how the 1st string visits the state 5 times and the 2nd string is not accepted, but I don't know the process for the 3rd and 4th strings. I would really appreciate it if someone could just walk through the states visited for the 3rd or 4th string because I keep getting stuck

Answer (score 0):

This PDA matches palindromes. How does it do it? It looks for `P` on the stack and replaces it with either `aPa` or `bPb`, then matches `a` on the stack with `a` in the input. Likewise for `b`. It replaces `P` nondeterminstically.

Let's walk through #3. We'll focus on `Q_loop`, which I'll just call `L` for simplicity. The top of the stack will be the rightmost character.

1. The first time we get to `L`, the input is `abba` and the stack is `$P`. We will nondeterministically follow the `e,P->a` transition.
2. The input is `abba`, the stack is `$aPa`. We will follow the `a,a->e` transition.
3. Input: `bba`, stack: `$aP`. Follow `e,P->b`.
4. Input: `bba`, stack: `$abPb`. Follow `b,b->e`.
5. Input: `ba`, stack: `$abP`. Follow `e,P->e`.
6. Input: `ba`, stack: `$ab`. Follow `b,b->e`.
7. Input: `a`, stack: `$a`. Follow `a,a->e`.
8. Input: e, stack, `$`. Follow `e,$->e` and accept in the next state.